# JavaScript Todo List - When I click 'edit' button, it selects the wrong text input, but still edits the correct item

Tags: javascript, html

```js
const todoList = {
  todos: [],

  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false
    });
    view.displayTodos();
  },

  changeTodo: function(position, newTodoText) {
    this.todos[position].todoText = newTodoText;
    view.displayTodos();
  },

  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    view.displayTodos();
  },

  toggleCompleted: function(position) {
    let todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
  },

  toggleAll: function() {
    const allTodos = this.todos.length;
    let completedTodos = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < allTodos; i++) {
      if (this.todos[i].completed === true) {
        completedTodos++;
      }
    }

    if (completedTodos === allTodos) {
      for (let i = 0; i < allTodos; i++) {
        this.todos[i].completed = false;
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < allTodos; i++) {
        this.todos[i].completed = true;
      }
    }

    view.displayTodos();
  }
};

const handlers = {
  toggleAll: function() {
    todoList.toggleAll();
  },

  addTodo: function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault(); // Ensure it is only this code that rusn
      let todoTextInput = document.getElementById('todoTextInput');
      todoList.addTodo(todoTextInput.value);
      todoTextInput.value = '';
    }
  },

  deleteTodo: function(position) {
    todoList.deleteTodo(position);
  }
};

const view = {

  displayTodos: function() {
    let todosUl = document.getElementById('todoList');
    todosUl.innerHTML = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < todoList.todos.length; i++) {
      let todoLi = document.createElement('li');
      let todoLiText = document.createElement('input');
      todoLiText.type = "text";
      todoLiText.disabled = true;
      todoLiText.id = 'textInput';
      let todoTextWithCompletion = todoList.todos[i].todoText;;
      let check = document.createElement('input');
      check.type = "checkbox";
      check.id = "checkbox";
      check.className = "checkbox";
      check.checked = '';

      todoLi.id = i;
      todoLiText.value = todoTextWithCompletion;
      todoLi.appendChild(check);
      todoLi.appendChild(todoLiText);
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
      todoLi.appendChild(this.createEditButton());
      todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);

      if (document.getElementById('checkbox').checked === true) {
        todoList.toggleCompleted(i);
      };
      if (todoList.todos[i].completed === true) {
        todoLiText.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      };

    }
  },

  createDeleteButton: function() {
    let deleteButton = document.createElement('a');
    deleteButton.href = "#";
    deleteButton.textContent = "Delete";
    deleteButton.className = 'x';
    return deleteButton;
  },

  createEditButton: function() {
    let editButton = document.createElement('a');
    editButton.href = "#";
    editButton.textContent = "edit";
    editButton.className = 'edit';
    return editButton;
  },

  setUpEventListeners: function() {
    let todosUl = document.getElementById('todoList');

    todosUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let elementClicked = event.target;

      if (elementClicked.className === 'x') {
        handlers.deleteTodo(parseInt(elementClicked.parentNode.id));
      };
    });

    // Edit List Item
    todosUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let elementClicked = event.target;
      let position = elementClicked.parentNode.id;

      if (elementClicked.className === 'edit') {
        let input = document.getElementById('textInput');

        input.disabled = false;
        input.className += " activeTextInput ";

        input.focus();
        input.select();

        input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
          let elementClicked = event.target;

          if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            let textInput = input.value;
            input.disabled = true;
            input.classList.remove("activeTextInput");
            todoList.changeTodo(position, textInput);
          };
        });
      };
    });

    // Line through on check
    todosUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      let elementClicked = event.target;
      let position = elementClicked.parentNode.id;
      let check = document.getElementById('checkbox');

      if (elementClicked.className === 'checkbox') {
        todoList.toggleCompleted(position);
        check.checked = true;
      };
    });

    //Delete All
    let clearAll = document.getElementById('clearAll');

    clearAll.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
      todoList.todos.splice(0, todoList.todos.length);
      view.displayTodos();
    });

    // TODO Delete Selected

  }
};

view.setUpEventListeners();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: #eeeeee !important;
}

h1 {
  color: #282845 !important;
}

p {
  opacity: .3;
}

.container {
  min-height: 70%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50% !important;
}

#todoTextInput {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: .7;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.2);
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  font-style: italic;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.1);
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.2);
  min-width: inherit;
}

li a {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
  opacity: .3 !important;
  transition: .2s;
}

li a:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(5, 5, 5, 0..01);
  background-color: inherit;
}

li input[type="text"] {
  padding: none;
  border: none;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: .5s;
}

.activeTextInput {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.1);
  padding: 10px !important;
}

input[type="text"] {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.01);
  padding: 0;
}

input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input:checked+input[type="text"] {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  opacity: .5;
}

.btn {
  background-color: white !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px rgba(5, 5, 5, 0.2);
  margin-top: -2px !important;
  font-style: italic;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#clearAll {
  margin-top: -21px !important;
}

.hidden {
  display: none !important;
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center">List+</h1>

    <div class="row list-head">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a List Item" style="width: 100%" id="todoTextInput" onkeyup="handlers.addTodo(event)">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row list-container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <ul id="todoList">

        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn" style="width: 100%" id="clearAll">Clear All</button>
        <button class="btn" style="width: 100%">Clear Selected</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p class="text-center"><i>Created by Connor Beam</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm building a todo list in vanilla JavaScript. I'm trying to get the 'edit' option to function properly. When I click the 'edit' button, the corresponding text input should be enabled, and auto-selected, then the user should be able to press 'enter' to submit changes.

However, no matter which 'edit' button is clicked, he first text input is always selected, while still changing the correct item when submitted.

Here's a working link to the most recent version: http://vanillajstodo.surge.sh/

I believe the problem is that all 'todoLiText' inputs are being created with the same id; however, I'm not sure how to fix that.

Let me know if more info is needed.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: You're creating multiple elements with `id="textinput"`. IDs should be unique. `getElementById('textinput')` will always select the first one.

Comment: Use a class instead of an ID, and select the element with that class in the same LI.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I'll see if I can get it to work using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this solution:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YQQovp?editors=1010

```
let input = document.getElementById(position).childNodes[1];
```

Your mistake is that you should never have multiple elements with the same id on the same page. Instead you should use the same class in that situation.

Comment: Thank you. I figured the id was the problem, but didn't know how to go about fixing it.